# Openemr sample database

Tags: mysql, content-management-system

I am building a custom portal for OpenEMR. So I need some appropriate data feeded into the database. Do you know any link where some sample databases are available to populate my installation of OpenEMR

Comment: For downloading the sample patients visit http://demo.open-emr.org:2101/sql/openemr/example_patient_data.sql

Answer (score 3):

Brady Miller of the OpenEMR project previously [commented on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/openemr/discussion/202505/thread/ef81863f#2fd9):

> Several possibilities:
>
> 1. Scrape the pertinent tables from the online demo: http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_Demo
> 2. Use the example_patient_data.sql and example_patient_users.sql scripts in the sql directory
> 3. Use the PrintaPatient data generator; details of this program can be found here: http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_Tools

Answer (score 0):

There is this project that can generate patients in FHIR  format and a lot of file formats (csv, json, xml, etc) and you can find it [here](https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea)
In the `README` it explains how to use it, it's pretty simple, simply run `run-synthea` and will generate a patient. You can also use `run-synthea -p 1000` and will generate 1000 patients.
It's only synthetic data, but except for the PHIs, the data is quite good.